# Неожиданное переполнение константы там, где его быть не должно

Tags: c++, visual-studio, integer-overflow

Почему, когда я пишу вот такой код:

```
size_t VRamSize = 2048 * 1024 * 1024;
```

то получаю предупреждение *"Переполнение константы"*?

> warning C4307: '*' : integral constant overflow

`size_t` у меня `unsigned long long` (самый большой тип), у него диапазон, внимание,

> 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615

`2048 * 1024 * 1024 = 2147483648`
(посчитайте, насколько меньше знаков).

Что значит это предупреждение?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В процессе самого умножения, вы перемножаете константы типа `int`, и только потом приводите результат к типу ull. Так что используйте соответствующие суффиксы (не знаю, какие они точно в студии), типа `1024llu`.

Или можно явно приводить тип сразу `size_t(1024)*1024*2048`.

Comment: Суффиксы [стандартизированы](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.icon#2).